# How to install new system (with new applications) without removing /home

Tags: upgrade, filesystem, re-installation

I'd like to update to 11.04 from 10.10 (but I don't like upgrading system, I prefer full reinstalling)
I'd like to install whole new system, but I want to keep my `/home` folders (Music, Movies, Documents and so on). If I keep `/home` while installing - this will keep all my program settings too (but I have lots of trash there too, and 'd like to clean it too).

Can I delete all `.folders` in `/home` and then reinstall system (keeping old `/home`) ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have your `/home` on a separate partition you can install 11.04 without losing the data in `/home` without problems. Just make sure to use manual partitioning during installation, declare your existing partitions as `/` and `/home`, and make sure that `/` gets formatted but `/home` does not.

You should still make a backup though, anything else would be negligent.

Also, if you want to keep your documents but not necessarily your user settings (as you mentioned to have lots of 'trash' there) you can just create a new user after you installed the new system, and move your files there.

Comment: I have `/home` on a separate partition... But I like idea with a new user, thnx

Comment: Adapted my answer to that new piece of info. ;)